# Client winform and server's web services communication project

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, web-services

I'm a trainee in a company that leases a music product. The service consists of an automated mp3 player and daily renewals/updates of songs downloaded to clients machines. A winform app installed on clients compares the records count of the server and client databases holding the songs. If there is a difference (the server db has more records than the client db) the missing mp3 file is downloaded on the client through gbridge and the database is updated with the new entries. 
With the current system we are forced to send all of the mp3 files the database holds to our clients, 25.000 files aprox even though our music is categorized in genres. Most of our clients, will never play songs from all of the categories.

We want to replace the gbridge way and write a .NET solution that will handle the client/server communication, the downloading of the files and the update of the databases. We want to change the pricing policy and charge by category so from a web page aspx or php, the clients will be able to choose the categories they want to update with new songs.

How can this be done? What technologies are needed? How hard will it be to implement considering that we are 2 developers, my boss who has some experience but mostly with previous versions of the framework and myself, a beginner as I mentioned with small experience in winforms and asp.net webforms though I have never written a web service.

Answer (score 0):

> How hard will it be to implement considering that we are 2 developers,
>   my boss who has some experience but mostly with previous versions of
>   the framework and myself, a beginner as I mentioned with small
>   experience in winforms and asp.net webforms though I have never
>   written a web service.

It will be this hard:

```
<------------------------------------------------------------->
```

Honestly?

Comment: I'm just asking for directions on what I should study and what technologies fit my needs. Alright I know its gonna be hard, but I'm willing to work hard study and learn.

Comment: @Pantelis you can do all that with a bit of business logic and some web-services. Study a bit of WCF and see if you can come up with some useful service methods that you can call from your windows app. If in doubt, ask another and more specific question.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate this answear much more than being ironic.